# Android App - returning Null Pointer Exception on Eclair

Tags: java, android

I am having an issue with an Android app I am writing.  It crashes on Eclair due to a `NullPointerException` but runs fine on Froyo and Gingerbread.  Can anyone tell me how to rewrite this to avoid the Null Pointer Exception?  Thanks in advance.

**Edit**
I added the stack trace and logcat, I might have read it wrong originally, looks like it could be my `TabWidget`?

logcat references this line in my `Home` class:

```
tabHost.addTab(tabHost.newTabSpec("tab1").setIndicator("Snow", res.getDrawable(R.drawable.weather2)).setContent(new Intent(this,FirstTab.class)));
```

**Logcat**

```
ERROR/AndroidRuntime(314): java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to start activity ComponentInfo{com.wilcoxis.android.kirkwood/com.wilcoxis.android.Home}: java.lang.NullPointerException
ERROR/AndroidRuntime(314):     at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2496)
ERROR/AndroidRuntime(314):     at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2512)
ERROR/AndroidRuntime(314):     at android.app.ActivityThread.access$2200(ActivityThread.java:119)
ERROR/AndroidRuntime(314):     at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1863)
ERROR/AndroidRuntime(314):     at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:99)
ERROR/AndroidRuntime(314):     at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:123)
ERROR/AndroidRuntime(314):     at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:4363)
ERROR/AndroidRuntime(314):     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
ERROR/AndroidRuntime(314):     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:521)
ERROR/AndroidRuntime(314):     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:860)
ERROR/AndroidRuntime(314):     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:618)
ERROR/AndroidRuntime(314):     at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
ERROR/AndroidRuntime(314): Caused by: java.lang.NullPointerException
ERROR/AndroidRuntime(314):     at android.widget.TabWidget.onFocusChange(TabWidget.java:351)
ERROR/AndroidRuntime(314):     at android.view.View.onFocusChanged(View.java:2622)
ERROR/AndroidRuntime(314):     at android.view.View.handleFocusGainInternal(View.java:2445)
ERROR/AndroidRuntime(314):     at android.view.ViewGroup.handleFocusGainInternal(ViewGroup.java:404)
ERROR/AndroidRuntime(314):     at android.view.View.requestFocus(View.java:3562)
ERROR/AndroidRuntime(314):     at android.view.ViewGroup.requestFocus(ViewGroup.java:976)
ERROR/AndroidRuntime(314):     at android.view.ViewGroup.onRequestFocusInDescendants(ViewGroup.java:1021)
ERROR/AndroidRuntime(314):     at android.view.ViewGroup.requestFocus(ViewGroup.java:977)
ERROR/AndroidRuntime(314):     at android.view.ViewGroup.onRequestFocusInDescendants(ViewGroup.java:1021)
ERROR/AndroidRuntime(314):     at android.view.ViewGroup.requestFocus(ViewGroup.java:980)
ERROR/AndroidRuntime(314):     at android.view.ViewGroup.onRequestFocusInDescendants(ViewGroup.java:1021)
ERROR/AndroidRuntime(314):     at android.view.ViewGroup.requestFocus(ViewGroup.java:977)
ERROR/AndroidRuntime(314):     at android.view.ViewGroup.onRequestFocusInDescendants(ViewGroup.java:1021)
ERROR/AndroidRuntime(314):     at android.view.ViewGroup.requestFocus(ViewGroup.java:980)
ERROR/AndroidRuntime(314):     at android.view.View.requestFocus(View.java:3513)
ERROR/AndroidRuntime(314):     at android.view.View.requestFocus(View.java:3491)
ERROR/AndroidRuntime(314):     at android.widget.TabHost.setCurrentTab(TabHost.java:334)
ERROR/AndroidRuntime(314):     at android.widget.TabHost.addTab(TabHost.java:213)
ERROR/AndroidRuntime(314):     at com.wilcoxis.android.Home.onCreate(Home.java:83)
ERROR/AndroidRuntime(314):     at android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnCreate(Instrumentation.java:1047)
ERROR/AndroidRuntime(314):     at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2459)
ERROR/AndroidRuntime(314):     ... 11 more
```

**Stack Trace**

```
DalvikVM[localhost:8610]    
    Thread [<3> main] (Suspended (exception NullPointerException))  
        TabWidget.onFocusChange(View, boolean) line: 351    
        TabWidget(View).onFocusChanged(boolean, int, Rect) line: 2622   
        TabWidget(View).handleFocusGainInternal(int, Rect) line: 2445   
        TabWidget(ViewGroup).handleFocusGainInternal(int, Rect) line: 404   
        TabWidget(View).requestFocus(int, Rect) line: 3562  
        TabWidget(ViewGroup).requestFocus(int, Rect) line: 976  
        LinearLayout(ViewGroup).onRequestFocusInDescendants(int, Rect) line: 1021   
        LinearLayout(ViewGroup).requestFocus(int, Rect) line: 977   
        TabHost(ViewGroup).onRequestFocusInDescendants(int, Rect) line: 1021    
        TabHost(ViewGroup).requestFocus(int, Rect) line: 980    
        FrameLayout(ViewGroup).onRequestFocusInDescendants(int, Rect) line: 1021    
        FrameLayout(ViewGroup).requestFocus(int, Rect) line: 977    
        PhoneWindow$DecorView(ViewGroup).onRequestFocusInDescendants(int, Rect) line: 1021  
        PhoneWindow$DecorView(ViewGroup).requestFocus(int, Rect) line: 980  
        PhoneWindow$DecorView(View).requestFocus(int) line: 3513    
        PhoneWindow$DecorView(View).requestFocus() line: 3491   
        TabHost.setCurrentTab(int) line: 334    
        TabHost.addTab(TabHost$TabSpec) line: 213   
        Home.onCreate(Bundle) line: 83  
        Instrumentation.callActivityOnCreate(Activity, Bundle) line: 1047   
        ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread$ActivityRecord, Intent) line: 2459  
        ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread$ActivityRecord, Intent) line: 2512   
        ActivityThread.access$2200(ActivityThread, ActivityThread$ActivityRecord, Intent) line: 119 
        ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(Message) line: 1863  
        ActivityThread$H(Handler).dispatchMessage(Message) line: 99 
        Looper.loop() line: 123 
        ActivityThread.main(String[]) line: 4363    
        Method.invokeNative(Object, Object[], Class, Class[], Class, int, boolean) line: not available [native method]  
        Method.invoke(Object, Object...) line: 521  
        ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run() line: 860  
        ZygoteInit.main(String[]) line: 618 
        NativeStart.main(String[]) line: not available [native method]  
    Thread [<13> Binder Thread #2] (Running)    
    Thread [<11> Binder Thread #1] (Running)
```

Comment: `The last function to be called before it breaks is String[]` String[] isn't a function, it's the return type. The function is updateData(). And also declaring a method `throws Exception` is bad. You should only explicitly declare throwable what you know you can throw.

Comment: And what does your logcat print. It's pretty clear that if data is null after the function call, the function threw an exception.

Answer (score 0):

You're not handling the case where you get an empty string back from the service.  Actually, you're not handling any cases of failure.  Check that you're getting valid data back, and don't operate on reference variables (like your string array) that could potentially be null

Comment: Thanks Rich.  I added in some handling for a null return on that service call.  I updated the post though because it looks like the problem is actually with my tabwidget.  Thanks a lot.